# How to split html?

Tags: java, html

There are many tags in my test html

```
<html
<div
..
<tr class="myClass" 
/tr>
<tr...


...

</html>
```

How can i get `<tr class="myClass" ... /tr>` out of the whole html file and put it into a string ?

Comment: By using an HTML parsing utility such as Jsoup. The specifics of the extraction will depend on the specifics of your need, for instance how you determine which element of the entire HTML is the one you wish to extract. You have not yet told us this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [**jsoup**](http://jsoup.org/), it can be as simple as::

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/").get();
Element myClassRow = doc.select("tr.myClass").first();
String myClassRowHTML = myClassRow.html();
```